# Wrong order of SQL Server's partitions

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, database-partitioning

I created database

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE DATABASE [testdb]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'testdb', FILENAME = N'D:\MSSQL\Data\testdb.mdf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB ), 
 FILEGROUP [2016] 
( NAME = N'2016', FILENAME = N'D:\MSSQL\Data\2016.ndf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB ), 
 FILEGROUP [2017] 
( NAME = N'2017', FILENAME = N'D:\MSSQL\Data\2017.ndf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB ), 
 FILEGROUP [2018] 
( NAME = N'2018', FILENAME = N'D:\MSSQL\Data\2018.ndf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB ), 
 FILEGROUP [2019] 
( NAME = N'2019', FILENAME = N'D:\MSSQL\Data\2019.ndf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB ), 
 FILEGROUP [2020] 
( NAME = N'2020', FILENAME = N'D:\MSSQL\Data\2020.ndf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'testdb_log', FILENAME = N'D:\MSSQL\Data\testdb_log.ldf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
GO
ALTER DATABASE [testdb] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130
GO
```

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ticket2](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [datesell] [datetime] NULL,
    [status] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Next, I've added partitions for this table

```
USE [testdb]
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [byYear](datetime) AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (N'2015-12-31T23:59:59', N'2017-01-01T00:00:00', N'2018-01-01T00:00:00', N'2019-01-01T00:00:00', N'2020-01-01T00:00:00')

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [years] AS PARTITION [byYear] TO ([PRIMARY], [2016], [2017], [2018], [2019], [2020])

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ClusteredIndex_on_years_636227525068063988] ON [dbo].[ticket2]
(
    [datesell]
)WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [years]([datesell])

DROP INDEX [ClusteredIndex_on_years_636227525068063988] ON [dbo].[ticket2]

COMMIT TRANSACTION
GO
```

When, I add some data into my table, I see next 
[image: Data in partitions]

Next, I've added one more partition for the next year

```
ALTER DATABASE testdb
ADD FILEGROUP [2021]

ALTER DATABASE testdb
ADD FILE
( NAME = N'2021', FILENAME = N'D:\MSSQL\Data\2021.ndf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB ) TO FILEGROUP [2021] 

ALTER PARTITION SCHEME [years] NEXT USED [2021];
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION byYear() split RANGE (N'2022-01-01T00:00:00' )

BEGIN TRANSACTION
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ClusteredIndex_on_years_636227647501414735] ON [dbo].[ticket2]
(
    [datesell]
)WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [years]([datesell])
DROP INDEX [ClusteredIndex_on_years_636227647501414735] ON [dbo].[ticket2]
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

And I see wrong partitions order. 
[image: Wrong partitions order]

Partition 2020 is still the last, but the last partition must be 2021. And all data with sell date more than 01/01/2022 will be in partition 2020, but I expected to see them in partition 2021.

Why it is so?

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the N'2021-01-01T00:00:00' for Partition 2020?

```
USE [testdb]
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [byYear](datetime) AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (N'2015-12-31T23:59:59', N'2017-01-01T00:00:00', N'2018-01-01T00:00:00', N'2019-01-01T00:00:00', N'2020-01-01T00:00:00', N'2021-01-01T00:00:00')

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [years] AS PARTITION [byYear] TO ([PRIMARY], [2016], [2017], [2018], [2019], [2020])

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ClusteredIndex_on_years_636227525068063988] ON [dbo].[ticket2]
(
    [datesell]
)WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [years]([datesell])

DROP INDEX [ClusteredIndex_on_years_636227525068063988] ON [dbo].[ticket2]

COMMIT TRANSACTION
GO
```

Comment: No. Please, take a look at this picture to better understand my idea http://ybex.com/d/2vnbd727moz9cq5g8uoiispla9j02wp8mmyz8147.html